# Mysql: similarity between an array of numbers with millions of other arrays

Tags: mysql, arrays, similarity

I have an array of 50 numbers:

```
54,12,79,34,66,22,78,192,54,23,55,87,23,63... (up to 50)
```

And a stack of a million of arrays of 50 numbers each:

```
  1: 76,34,67,4,12,34... (up to 50)
  2: 34,12,68,97,55,33... (up to 50)
  3: 21,65,87,23,65,45... (up to 50)
  4: ....
  5: (up to one million)
```

1) How can I store this in a MySQL database optimized ?

2) And most important, how can I compare the first array to know the similarity with the other arrays ? I mean ... I would like to have:

```
Similarity to 1: 13%
Similarity to 2: 11%
Similarity to 3: 16%
...
```

The similarity should run one by one element ... the first with the first, the second with the second, ... and then generate an average of similarity for the 50 elements.

Comment: what is your algorithm for determining similarity?

Comment: Is the order of the arrays significant in determining similarity?

Comment: Look at combination and/or permutation mathematics. The bad news is that this isn't what MySQL's great at.

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important you can store them as a sorted arrays:

```
    1: 4,12,34,34,67,76... (up to 50)
    2: 12,33,34,55,68,97... (up to 50)
    3: 21,23,45,65,65,87... (up to 50)
```

So with sorted arrays you can get a difference between any two sequences very simply by using the algorithm similar to a sorted arrays merge algorithm, so with sorting you get a O(n*logn) time.

But if you need to compare and if there are reasonable upper and lower limits, you can just enumerate all the unique numbers of all the sequences, i.e.:

```
    0  => 4
    1  => 12
    2  = >21
    3  => 23
    4  => 33  
    5  => 34
    6  => 45
    7  => 55
    8  => 65 
    9  => 67
    10 => 68
    11 => 76
    12 => 87
```

store them as a sequence of counters, i.e.:

```
    1: 1100020001010
    2: 0100110100101
    3: 0011001020001
```

So the difference is a number of differing numbers divided to a total amount of characters, but really I can't see any advantages of this method because it also works or O(n*logn).

Comment: This suggestion would not be viable given the constraints required by the person posting the question. Sorting would modify the similarity, and the user does not want them to be sorted first, then compared. He wants them compared as-is.

Comment: @robotsushi in that case he can just use two Map<int,int> with counters of number occurences and then compare them and calculate the similarity obviouly

Comment: Your suggestion requires to process the same information twice, in two different ways. First, to see if elements in the array are similar, then store the binary data regarding their similarity in another array, then process _that_ array again to actually perform the calculation of similarity. It just seems like too much work and processing.

Comment: @robotsushi yes because Map inserting of single item works for O(logn), reading of one item also works for O(logn), so we can do all the operations with Map by O(n*logn), and obvious way of array-to-array comparison without using Map or sorting works for O(n*n) that is quite slower

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. What is O(n*logn) and O(n*n)???? How is that relevant to anything in this question? And where is this Map function you speak of??

Comment: @robotsusji I'm talking about algorithm complexity, a Map is not a function but a common name of a data structure — associative storage based on a tree (possibly with hash) with some strict performance requirements, i.e. it is implemented as [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) in C++, and PHP also has something like it (named associative arrays) but I didn't sure that associative arrays has the same performance

Comment: @robotsushi Why? There is a million of arrays, and a decition with a better performance will do the work faster, you are a strange person

Comment: I would like for you to not just suggest a couple of haphazardly chosen algorithms, but actually write some PHP and do it yourself. Then, we will see which is the faster solution.

Comment: @robotsushi please learn at least [this](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) before

Comment: Your previous comment was about as helpful as the answer you provided. Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going. It is accurate under the assumption that **all** the arrays you will use will contain the same amount of elements, as you mentioned in your initial question.

```
<?php
$base = array(636,3305,705,3080,1895,3586,1879,817,3330,2884,487,1267,1016,2100,3598,2535,3894,2945,282,1182,3785,2489,3812,2829,1332,229,3577,125,2735,1126,1194,3366,430,1895,2446,2321,1480,325,3133,809,3204,3616,2071,220,1715,1669,2750,1608,613,3028);

$compare_a = array(355,3118,1293,2333,3632,2652,2677,1360,1295,1478,2742,1157,2545,2151,1593,3992,601,1913,1317,3728,581,3325,2612,1710,1430,1985,399,2731,2408,3821,1563,2759,2939,2852,1091,2570,1503,3764,3926,2794,1241,2668,3947,3782,818,1540,3774,1414,3449,1091);

$compare_b = array(1821,2179,1411,1559,193,3304,1484,2125,2722,1879,2031,2611,1142,928,1372,2140,1230,1498,1250,1362,287,3055,2933,186,3310,3397,3665,2196,691,7,3677,2508,2182,1088,66,2371,391,1546,495,3108,3421,2522,1719,563,3446,3087,2698,676,584,3944);

$compare_c = array(3354,3250,2884,1803,3844,1981,2882,1998,1196,1959,495,3514,3284,844,1848,2834,2415,459,3158,1862,1123,2334,491,3668,1136,406,4000,3854,2326,2169,2250,1680,1419,1133,3478,1262,3110,2359,3255,305,318,3745,3814,3598,589,1662,2431,2999,2116,1589);

$compare_d = array(1474,3489,2708,1704,2086,3248,2817,3403,467,3783,3208,3348,2426,595,3998,2089,2948,3546,189,2510,1723,1054,2364,3330,3480,3553,697,2268,3544,2338,374,1017,1827,3077,2717,3908,2325,1533,3310,2788,1316,2518,2135,3737,3109,2133,1826,2056,1678,2011);

$compare_e = array(2688,2677,3180,154,1614,3138,3234,3219,2160,3929,3951,2577,2157,1592,174,148,604,2921,1681,2425,1334,45,2550,2421,3833,47,716,2117,459,3702,3997,3142,2378,3177,3292,3988,2315,2525,3206,474,2453,3157,3047,610,748,3217,753,1347,2137,2430);

$similar = abs(((count(array_diff($base, $compare_a)) -count($base)) / count($base)) * 100);
print '1) $base compared with $compare_a is: '. $similar .'% similar to $base<br />';

$similar = abs(((count(array_diff($base, $compare_b)) -count($base)) / count($base)) * 100);
print '2) $base compared with $compare_b is: '. $similar .'% similar to $base<br />';

$similar = abs(((count(array_diff($base, $compare_c)) -count($base)) / count($base)) * 100);
print '3) $base compared with $compare_c is: '. $similar .'% similar to $base<br />';

$similar = abs(((count(array_diff($base, $compare_d)) -count($base)) / count($base)) * 100);
print '4) $base compared with $compare_d is: '. $similar .'% similar to $base<br />';

$similar = abs(((count(array_diff($base, $compare_e)) -count($base)) / count($base)) * 100);
print '5) $base compared with $compare_e is: '. $similar .'% similar to $base<br />';
?>
```

The above code should spit this out for you:

```
1) $base compared with $compare_a is: 0% similar to $base
2) $base compared with $compare_b is: 2% similar to $base
3) $base compared with $compare_c is: 4% similar to $base
4) $base compared with $compare_d is: 2% similar to $base
5) $base compared with $compare_e is: 0% similar to $base
```

It really depends on what you want to use as an algorithm to determine similarity. In your question you say you want each element to be compared to another element in the same position. PHP's built-in function [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff) does this for you. A full-blown example would depend on how you are retreiving these arrays. I could modify this to pull data from a database and then run the calculations within a loop, or something. But I'd need more details in order to help you in that regard.

Comment: And this will be fast with a million of records in a database ? :P

Comment: Haha, the speed would be determined by the computational resources of the machine it's running on. Processing power, RAM, etc. At a certain point, the speed is determined by the use of clever programming and data manipulation that concludes the same results, but reaches them with less resource intensive code. Of course, if that's what you want, pull out your check-book ;)